Invalid Padding when using b64.b32hexdecode
I get this:

binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

When using b32hexdecode in the last for loop in my decrypt function.
Here is my code:
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import base64 as b64,random as rd
def encryt(data):
    key=Fernet.generate_key()
    data=bytes(data,"utf-8")
    key2=rd.randint(0,5)
    for i in range(key2):
        data=b64.a85encode(data)
        data=b64.b32hexencode(data)
    fernet=Fernet(key)
    encrypted=fernet.encrypt(data)
    for i in range(key2):
        encrypted=b64.b32hexencode(encrypted)
        encrypted=b64.a85encode(encrypted)
    for i in range(key2):
        key=b64.b64encode(key)
        key=b64.a85encode(key)
        key=b64.b32hexencode(key)
    final=b64.b85encode(bytes(str(key2),"utf-8")).decode()+"/?\\"+encrypted.decode()+"~`~"+key.decode()
    return(final)
def decrypt(data):
    a=data.split("/?\\")
    key2=int(b64.b85decode(bytes(a[0],"utf-8")))
    b=a[1].split("~`~")
    encrypted=bytes(b[0],"utf-8")
    key=bytes(b[1],"utf-8")
    for i in range(key2):
        key=b64.b32hexdecode(key)
        key=b64.a85decode(key)
        key=b64.b64decode(key)
    for i in range(key2):
        encrypted=b64.a85decode(encrypted)
        try:encrypted=b64.b32hexdecode(encrypted)
        except Exception as e:encrypted=b64.b32hexdecode(encrypted+b'==')
    fernet=Fernet(key)
    decrypted=fernet.decrypt(encrypted)
    for i in range(key2):
        decrypted=b64.a85decode(decrypted)
        try:decrypted=b64.b32hexdecode(decrypted)
        except Exception as e:decrypted=b64.b32hexdecode(decrypted+b'=' * (4-len(decrypted) % 4))
    return(decrypted.decode())
a=encryt("testest:!2345t789&^543yehwqd7")
print(a,"\n",decrypt(a))

I tried using decrypted+b'==' and b'=' * (4-len(decrypted) % 4), but I was still getting the error.
Furthermore, sometimes when I run it, I get a

binascii.Error: Non-base32 digit found

error, and sometimes it just works.

The fundamental problem is pretty straightforward here (hint: use a debugger to inspect or just print the output of b32hexencode), but why is your encoding so convoluted? It’s not good for obfuscation or security, just messy and inconvenient.
